# Express JS - REST authentication and authorization

Tags: rest, express, azure-active-directory

I’m trying to  setup authentication & authorization for my Express based Node JS, REST API with azure AD. I’m not sure if that is possible without 3rd party libraries like Auth0.
API will be invoked from both client side (react, angular) & server side(asp.net, RPA) applications. I’d appreciate if you can share some tips on the architecture, examples and where authentication and authorization can be done. I think authentication will happen in the front-end(????).
End of the day I need these apis to be invoked only by authorized applications, users and I should be able to identify user’s invoking these apis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get your NodeJS apis protected with Azure AD. To achieve this, you can either use [MSAL-Node](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-node) or [Passport-Azure-AD](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) libraries. Once these APIs get protected by AAD, any front-end apps or back-end services calling your AAD protected APIs must fetch an access-token from AAD first and then use that access-token as bearer and call the AAD-protected APIs.

To get you started, you can refer to the following quickstart guides for both the libraries:

- Quickstart guide for MSAL-Node: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal
- Quickstart guide for Passport-Azure-AD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-nodejs-webapp